# How to ignore regex syntaxes in strings in bash

Tags: regex, bash

How do I ignore regex syntaxes in strings when using bash commands?

e.g. how do I ignore `\s` in:

`echo \sbananas`?

This prints out "sbananas", not "bananas"

I just need to solve the above problem in order to solve this problem:

I have a file which is a list of labels, but they are mixed up with regex syntaxes. First few lines of the file:

`\s1.1
\s1.2
\s2.1
\s2.2`

I am trying to loop through this file and use the labels to create directories (among other things). However, the regex syntax, namely `\s`, is inherited by the bash command I'm using, so I need to 'ignore' it.

This was solved by [Paul Hodges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8656552/paul-hodges) below, and I incorporated his code (`"${i#\s}"`) into my bash command:

`` for i in `cat <file>`; do mkdir -p "${i#\\s}"/txt ; done ``

Comment: There is no regexp here. The rules of using a backslash is part of the bash syntax. You don't want to change the bash parser, do you? If you want bananas, why then don't you write `echo bananas`?

Comment: Becasue my real problem is much more complex so I've simplified it. This is just one key part of the problem, and rather than ask how to solve the whole problem, I've just asked how to solve this part.

Comment: Then you should give a precise definition of the problem; the way you formulated it, I don't understand what you want to achieve exactly. That's why your posting has been "put on hold"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "ignore" them, to my knowledge. If you know exactly what the string is you could strip it -

```
$: x='\sbananas'
$: echo "$x"
\sbananas
$: echo "${x#\\s}"
bananas
```